# Operate RDD in SPARK, merge every 3 lines into one line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a copy of the data now, the data for each line is as follows。

```
A
B
C
QW
OO
P
...
```

Now I want to merge every three lines of behavior, as follows:

```
ABC
QWOOP
...
```

What should I code this function?

```
eg. val data = sc.textFile("path")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
val lineRdd = sc.textFile("path")

val yourRequiredRdd = lineRdd
  .zipWithIndex
  .map({ case (line, index) => (index / 3, (index, line)))
  .aggregateByKey(List.empty[(Long, String)])(
    { case (aggrList, (index, line)) => (index, line) :: aggrList },
    { case (aggrList1, aggrList2) => aggrList1 ++ aggrList2 }
  )
  .map({ case (key, aggrList) =>
    aggrList
      .sortBy({ case (index, line) => index })
      .map({ case (index, line) => line })
      .mkString("")
  })
```